# Logback can't access the specified logfiles

Tags: logback, websphere-liberty

I'm running my app on Websphere Liberty with logback logging. I defined an appender in logback.xml but on startup logback throws FileNotFoundException.

This is the error output:

```
09:37:33,065 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[RollApp] - Failed to create parent directories for [F:\server\wlp-ev-21.0.0.11\usr\servers\defaultServer\"F:\server\wlp-ev-21.0.0.11\usr\servers\defaultServer\logs\log-output.log]
09:37:33,066 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[RollApp] - openFile("F:/server/wlp-ev-21.0.0.11/usr/servers/defaultServer/logs/log-output.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: "F:\server\wlp-ev-21.0.0.11\usr\servers\defaultServer\logs\log-output.log (Die Syntax für den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datenträgerbezeichnung ist falsch)
    at java.io.FileNotFoundException: "F:\server\wlp-ev-21.0.0.11\usr\servers\defaultServer\logs\log-output.log (Die Syntax für den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datenträgerbezeichnung ist falsch)
```

Here's my appender block in logback.xml

```
    <appender name="RollApp"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>"${server.output.dir}/logs/log-output.log</File
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{2} - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>"${server.output.dir}/logs/log-output.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz</fileNamePattern
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
```

Did anyone ever encounter this problem?

I'm 100% sure the files exists because I can copy and paste the path from the error output into an explorer window and the file/folder opens!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the leading `"` is unexpected in the fileNamePattern.